# What is the best way to account for GC-content shift while constructing nucleotide-based phylogenetic tree?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, nucleotide-models

Let's say I want to construct a phylogenetic tree based on orthologous nucleotide sequences; I do not want to use protein sequences to have a better resolution. These species have different GC-content.

If we use a straightforward approach like maximum likelihood with JC69 or any other classical nucleotide model, conserved protein coding sequences of distant species with similar GC-content will artificially cluster together. This will happen because GC-content will mainly affect wobbling codon positions, and they will look similar on the nucleotide level.

What are possible ways to overcome this? I considered the following options so far:

1. Using protein sequence. This is possible of course, but we lose a lot of information on the short distance. Not applicable to non-coding sequences.
2. [Recoding](https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-15-S2-S8). In this approach C and T can be combined into a single pyrimidine state Y (G and A could be also combined in some implementations). This sounds interesting, but, first, we also lose some information here. Mathematical properties of the resulting process are not clear. As a result, this approach is not widely used.
3. Excluding third codon position from the analysis. Losing some short-distance information again. Also, not all synonymous substitution are specific to the third codon positions, so we still expect to have some bias. Not applicable to non-coding sequence.

It should be possible in theory to have a model which allows shifts in GC-content. This will be a non time-reversible Markov process. As far as I understand there are some computational difficulties estimating likelihood for such models.

Comment: I would just add that I think there's a key assumption in the setup here: "I do  not want to use protein sequences to have a better resolution". We can decompose 'better' here - it's likely to be more precise but also more biased, the latter for all the reasons you outline.

Comment: In case you might be interested, I tested some of the approaches you mention, plus a few other recoding schemes (http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.732758) in the following papers: http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1586 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msu105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are models that take into account compositional heterogeneity both under the [maximum likelihood](https://doi.org/10.1080/10635150600975218) and [Bayesian](https://doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msl091) frameworks. Although the substitution process is not time-reversible, the computations are [simplified by assuming](https://doi.org/10.1080/10635150490445779) that the instantaneous rate matrix can be decomposed into an "equilibrium frequency vector" (non-homogeneous) and a symmetric, constant exchange rate matrix.

I guess all your suggestions are also valid, and I remember recoding being used successfully to reduce the GC-content bias (examples in the references above and [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/molbev/msh137)).

Answer (score 3):

The following 2004 paper describes a way to model compositional changes across the tree, in a Bayesian framework: https://doi.org/10.1080/10635150490445779

A python package implementing this ("p4"), and improvements added along the years, is available here: https://github.com/pgfoster/p4-phylogenetics

To get started, you may find useful examples here: http://p4.nhm.ac.uk/scripts.html

This has been used in a few large-scale phylogenetic analyses.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the logDet algorithm was constructed to overcome GC% clustering.

At the time it was devised only a distance method was available/implemented, so it wasn't very powerful. The posts here imply that a Bayesian or ML approach are available and these do tightly stick to the model.

Original publication [here](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/13/10/1375/1020361)

Comment: Do you have a publication or webpage in mind? Can you link it?

Comment: Link provided above. Goes back a long way ... to 1996